# SPFile.MoveTo() changes content-type

Tags: sharepoint

Using SP2010. I got an SPWeb with two libraries (*sentApplicationsList* and *sentApplicationsListXml* in the code below). In one process, I need to move XML files from the first to the second library, so I wrote this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentApplicationsList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SPFile file = sentApplicationsList.Items[i].File;
    if (file != null && file.Name.EndsWith(".xml"))
    {
        string newUrl = sentApplicationsListXml.RootFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name;
        file.MoveTo(newUrl, true);
    }
}
```

When the item turns up in sentApplicationsListXml, it has the *Document* content-type, rather than my custom content-type. Why does SPFile.MoveTo() change the content-type? My content-type is activated in both libraries.

In an attempt to change the content-type back after MoveTo(), I added a few lines:

```
string newUrl = sentApplicationsListXml.RootFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name;
SPContentType contentType = file.Item.ContentType;
file.MoveTo(newUrl, true);
SPFile movedFile = web.GetFile(newUrl);
movedFile.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.ContentType] = contentType;
movedFile.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.ContentTypeId] = contentType.Id;
movedFile.Item.SystemUpdate();
```

This did not make any difference.